# Apply CSS to child DIV only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, let's say I have a similar structure like the one following :

```
<div comp-id='one'>
    <div comp-id='two'>
         <div comp-id='three'>
         ...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is to apply a hover effect to the child (in this case, the one with `comp-id="three"`).

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE :** I don't want to target *specifically* `[comp-id="three"]`. I want to target *any* child, with no-matter-which `comp-id` value. In the real-world example, there may be infinite nested `[comp-id]`ed `div`s. **I just need the innermost child.**

**What I'm trying to achieve :**

- User hovers over `three`, then **just** `three` is highlighted (not `one` and `two`)
- User hovers over `two`, then **just** `two` is highlighted (not `one` - and, of course, not `three`)

---

**My current CSS code :**

```
[comp-id]:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

However, my current CSS highlights everything which is not what I want. I could think of a javascript-based solution. What about CSS?

---

**Warning :** I'm not such a guru with CSS, so this *may* be really simple... :-)

Comment: Do you have a defined depth of your divs? Then you could access them by `div div div:hover { ... }` otherwise you can select that div by js using the `.find()` selector.

Comment: @DaKirsche Nope, unfortunately there's no pre-defined depth. Could you give me an example of how `.find()` could be used in this particular case?

Comment: Finding innermost child with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188933/how-do-i-select-the-innermost-element/4189310#4189310 (in your case it would be `$('[comp-id]:not(:has([comp-id]))')`. I don't think it's possible with pure CSS when nesting depth is not pre-deterined.

Comment: Now it looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364511/preventing-hover-event-of-a-div-triggering-on-parent-div

Comment: yup can't find how without a bit of js : http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/U3BrT/

Comment: @TecHunter Well, your code perfectly highlights on hover the child *and* the parents. However : **I just need the child**. :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I know! I was just providing a fiddle and stating that you need JS for that with `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @TecHunter I thought of that just after posting my comment - mea culpa! :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/U3BrT/14/ providing some tuning when mouse leave etc...

Comment: @TecHunter I've already managed to answer it... myself... lol. Thanks a lot, anyway! :-)

Answer (score 2):

And... well... thanks to @BMH, **this** is what worked :

```
$('[comp-id]:not(.hover)').mousemove(function(e){
    $('[comp-id]').removeClass('hover');
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('hover');

});
```

Comment: i think `e.stopPropagation();` as first line is better in an event function but can't find where I've read that

Comment: @TecHunter Hmm... Interesting. I think I'll follow your advice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a jQuery solution:

```
$('[comp-id]').mousemove(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
    $(e.target).addClass('hover'); 
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sMRMz/4/

Comment: Well, If I hover over `3` then 3 is highlighted. Which is great. However, when I hover over `2`, it's not... And the same goes for `1` as well...

Comment: It worked like what you've asked for before additional clarification.

Comment: I've updated my answer, your requirement changed significantly after several edits.

Comment: Well, your (last) answer did *not* solve the... riddle, either. However, you've helped **immensely** towards the solution (which I'm posting right now). And thanks a lot for that! (Hence, the +1) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in jQuery:

CSS:

```
.hoverableClass:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

JS:

```
function deepSearch(parent){
    var b_ClassAdd = true;
    if (!parent){
        parent = $('body');
        b_ClassAdd = false;
    }

    var allDivChilds = parent.find('div[comp-id]');
    if ((!allDivChilds || allDivChilds.length == 0) && b_ClassAdd)
        parent.addClass('hoverableClass'); 
    else
        for (var i = 0; i < allDivChilds.length; i++)
            deepSearch($(allDivChilds[i]));
}

deepSearch();
```

This code is untested and just an idea for a solution.

Comment: `$('[comp-id]:not(:has([comp-id]))').addClass('hoverableClass')` ;)

Comment: I do understand the point of your suggestion and it definitely is interesting. However, here's an issue : let's say we mark just the innermost child as `hoverable`. Then user hovers over its parent, and what is `hoverable` is its child, not itself. So I suppose we should take the innermost child on hover? Is this doable?

Comment: The function marks the innermost child of each div. It will make the same than the commented code of pawel. If a div does not have another child inside which is a div with attribute comp-id is is selected (parent) and get the class hoverableClass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '>' child selector for this,to stop the cascading styles

```
[comp-id]:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}

[comp-id]:hover > *{
  box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I've just tested it and it seems like it does the exact opposite (= highlight just the parent)

Comment: Try Interchanging the styles, and i guess some tweaking is also required. Then you might reach desired effect