# jquery get the last element at the end of a tree

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

If I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>blah</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there jquery to target the deepest elements (where the blahs are located)?

Comment: `$('div:contains(blah)')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select the innermost element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188933/how-do-i-select-the-innermost-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will select anything that doesn't have any child elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/YWARr/

```
$('div:not(:has(*))')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        //do something
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of recursive jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(deepest($("div:first")).html());

    function deepest(f){
        if(f.find("div").length)return deepest(f.find("div"));
        else return f;
    }
});
```

Gets the first DIV with no children starting from whatever you pass to Deepest

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cBNL/6/)

Comment: Interesting concept, but your implementation won't work because `f.find("div")` is always true because it's just a jQuery object whether it has any DOM elements in it or not.  You can check `.length` to see if the jQuery object is empty.

Comment: All I did was add some more text to your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9cBNL/2/.  This logic `if(f.find("div"))` simply doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: It didn't return the right answer. The right answer would have been to just alert `blah` as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/9cBNL/3/. You also didn't actually recurse.

Comment: You're right... I stand corrected... thanks for the lesson :)

Comment: there was more wrong as well, the recursive didn't actually go into recursion. All fixed now and working. For whoever is looking for a recursive solution :)