# Html selecting lowest level child element?

Tags: html, .net

I'm currently using CsQuery which is similar to HtmlAgilityPack, it allows you manipulate a virtual dom as .net objects. I'm currently trying to iterate through a html table so that I can build a datatable from it, however the cells are mixed whether they're nested in divs or anchor tags so it's not always the same selector. Is there a css selector I can use that will find the lowest level child element?

Here's an example of a table I am trying to select from.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>TestCol1</th>
        <th>TestCol2</th>
        <th>TestCol3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div><a>41</a></div></td>
        <td><div>Testttttt</div></td>
        <td>Testestst</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I was to use the selectr 'tr td div a', I miss row 2 and 3. At the moment I am having to use if statements to try all three selector variations. In an ideal row I would use the selector and it would extract the inner text for every td.

If anything didn't make sense, please let me know and I will reiterate.

Comment: This might help you get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I select the innermost element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188933/how-do-i-select-the-innermost-element)

Basicaly you have to select all elements which do not have any childen.

Comment: Only one issue, I am using .tableheader *:not(:has(""*"")) however any that do not have any child elements do not get picked up. So if I had <th class="tableheader">Test</th>, it would not select it.

Comment: Fixed the above by using "th, th *:not(:has(""*""))"