# Remove Html tags and formatting but keep anchor tag in string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following string variable and want to replace all html tags and formatting but wants to keep anchor tag without formatting so it remain clickable.

```
content = "<div><a href=\"1\">I</a> was going here and then <a href=\"that\">that</a> happened.<p>Some Text here</p></div>";
```

It should be look like

```
content = "<a href=\"1\">I</a> was going here and then <a href=\"that\">that</a> happened. Some Text here"
```

Comment: Use regex and filter the words you want or the ones you don't want

Comment: @BunnyDhaliwal - bad idea. Better to create an HTML partial and parse the DOM. Angular implements jQLite, no?

Comment: I have try this but it also remove anchor tags.                                  value = value.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element - use [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) for example

Comment: @mplungjan yes of course that is an alternative as well however, OP asked how to remove certain things

Comment: angular.element(content).find("p").text() will get the text of the p tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following way to remove all tags except anchor tag.

```
  value = value.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
        let html = '', addToMax = false, extraLimit = 0;

        if(value && typeof value === 'string' && value.length) {
          let inDelete = false;

          for(let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if(value.charAt(i) == '<' && value.charAt(i + 1) && value.charAt(i + 1) != 'a') {
              inDelete = true;
              if(value.charAt(i + 1) == '/' && ((value.charAt(i + 2) && value.charAt(i + 2) == 'a') || (value.charAt(i + 2) == ' ') && value.charAt(i + 3) && value.charAt(i + 3) == 'a')) {
                inDelete = false;
              }
            }

            if(!inDelete) {
              html += value.charAt(i);
            }

            if(inDelete && value.charAt(i) == '>') {
              inDelete = false;
            }
          }
        }
        value = angular.copy(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
content = "<div><a href=\"1\">I</a> was going here and then <a href=\"that\">that</a> happened.<p>Some Text here</p></div>";

var output = content.replace(/(<\/?(?:a)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>/ig, '$1');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use RegEx to parse HTML

We could look into unwrap - here is one P with nothing inside

If there is something inside the P we would need to loop each tag

```js
const content = "<div><a href=\"1\">I</a> was going here and then <a href=\"that\">that</a> happened.<p>Some Text here</p></div>";
let $html = angular.element(content);

console.log($html.html());

const $p = $html.find("p");
$p.replaceWith($p.text());

console.log($html.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Any tag but A - still not handling tags wrapped in other tags - for that we would need to recursively loop out:

[How do I select the innermost element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188933/how-do-i-select-the-innermost-element)

```js
const content = "<div><a href=\"1\">I</a> was going here and then <a href=\"that\">that</a> happened.<p>Some Text here</p>. Here is a <span>span element1</span> some text <span>span element2</span></div>";
let $html = angular.element(content);

console.log($html.html());

const tags = $html.find("*");
for (let i=0;i<tags.length;i++) {
  const $tag = angular.element(tags[i]);
  const tagName = $tag[0].tagName;
  if (tagName==="A") continue; // ignore A
  $html.find(tagName).eq(0).replaceWith($tag.text()); // one at a time
};
console.log($html.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It may be possible to have any other Html tags, not only <p> Tag.

Comment: Its not correct if you add same tag with multiple times then it replace all same tag with same text.